# A black blinking box character on LCD

Tags: lcd

We have a machine which is using a timer and the timer has an LCD, a few of the displays, with no reason all of a sudden displays a black box blinking... If I switch off the machine from power switch and wait for 5-10 seconds, everything goes back to normal, but if I switch off and on very quickly, like in a second, it doesn't go away.

any leads ? ideas, you may give me would be helpful, 
Thank you

This only happens, maybe 10-20 lcds out of 1000 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the microcontroller is not being properly reset along with the [display controller](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/MIT/863.06/11.13/44780.pdf), so that the blinking cursor is being randomly displayed. If it does it in normal operation it is probably bad timing design in the firmware also.

[image]

Better reset hardware design and better firmware design and coding is probably the solution.